# Nested JSON object with Mysql and Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

My intention is to retrieve page section list with relevant pages on a array ofJson object.

For example:

```
[
    {
        "sectionid": "value1",
        "sectiondescription": "value1",
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageid": "id1",
                "pagedescription": "desription1",
            },
            {
                "pageid": "id2",
                "pagedescription": "desription2",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sectionid": "value2",
        "sectiondescription": "value2",
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageid": "id3",
                "pagedescription": "desription3",
            },
            {
                "pageid": "id4",
                "pagedescription": "desription4",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am using Nodejs with Mysql.

I use the below mysql query to retrieve the sections that are enabled for the given users role:

```
SELECT section.SectionId,section.Description
FROM section as section
INNER JOIN userroletosection AS urts
    ON section.SectionId = urts.SectionID
INNER JOIN user AS user
    ON user.RoleID = urts.UserRoleID
WHERE
    user.UserId = 1
```

And this query to retrieve the pages for the given section:

```
SELECT p.PageID,p.Description,p.URL
FROM page AS p
INNER JOIN sectiontopage AS stp
    ON p.PageID = stp.PageID
WHERE
    stp.SectionID = ?
```

I need to know how to run the query using a loop and construct a Json array object using nodejs and mysql.

Here I Have attached the nodejs code

conn.query('SELECT * From section as section INNER JOIN userroletosection AS urts ON section.SectionId = urts.SectionID INNER JOIN user AS user ON user.RoleID = urts.UserRoleID WHERE user.UserId = 1',(err,rows,fileds)=>{

```
if(!err)
{

  for (var i = 0;i < rows.length; i++) {

    conn.query('SELECT p.PageID,p.Description,p.URL FROM page AS p INNER JOIN sectiontopage AS stp ON p.PageID = stp.PageID    WHERE stp.SectionID = ?',[rows[i].SectionId],(err2,rows2,fileds)=>{
      if(!err2)
     {

      for(var j =0; j<rows2.length;j++)
      {
        obj2.push({ PID: JSON.stringify(rows2[j].PageID),
          PageID: rows2[j].PageID,
          PageDescription: rows2[j].Description,
          PageUrl: rows2[j].URL
        })


      }


        console.log(obj2);

    }
    })
    {
       objs.push({ID: JSON.stringify(rows[i].SectionId),
          ID: rows[i].SectionId,
          sectionDesciption: rows[i].Description,
          Pages: obj2
        });
    }


  }
```

Comment: Can you put the nodejs code to see what are you doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You are going to have to use the MySQL JSON functions to be able to access the items within the JSON document, such as JSON_EXTRACT and JSON_CONTAINS